# Pass variables to PHP file download script

Tags: php, download

Here's my main form and download script. I need to pass some variables to download.php. These variables are derived from html select-list. How do I pass these variables to download.php?
Here's my main form -

```
<td align="left"><select name="loc" id="loc" class="select-list">
    <option value="\">Choose</option>                                       
    <option value="aa">AA</br>
    <option value="bb">BB</br>
    </select>   
</td>
<strong>Click below to download:</strong> </br></br>
<span class="button" ><a href="download.php">Download (CSV)</a></span>
```

Here's my download.php code -

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=table.csv");
header("Content-type: text/csv");
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
echo $out;
exit;
```

Now I want to pass the selected value from select-list to the download.php so that I can use predicates in my MYSQL SELECT query.

Any inputs please?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is very, very basic PHP. You are probably best off working through a tutorial that covers this.

Comment: @Pekka I'm sorry, but I'm relatively new to PHP, Javascript stuff. Can you give some pointers please. I didnt find any help on the internet for this. Thanks

Comment: Use $_POST or $_GET ( depending on the method your form uses to submit data ) to access the value of the selected item in your form your from download.php like so. You will use the name attribute of your form elements ( in this case your select box's name `loc` ) to get the values carried over to PHP script. Example `$selectedValue = $_POST['loc'];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure if this is what you mean, but hopefully it helps.

You need to use a HTML form with server-side PHP to handle the input.
Try looking at [w3schools' tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp). Here's a (very basic) example:

In the form:

```
<form action="download.php" method="post">
<select name="loc" id="loc" class="select-list">
<option value="\">Choose</option>                                       
<option value="aa">AA</br>
<option value="bb">BB</br>
</select>   
<input type="submit" value="Download" />
</form>
```

In the download.php:

```
<?php
$val=$_POST['loc']; //this equals either aa or bb
if($val == 'aa') {
  // do whatever 
} else if($val == 'bb') {
  // do whatever
} else {
  echo "Error";
}
?>
```

Also, make sure you sanitize your database queries, as well as initialize the db. [w3schools link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp)

Comment: OMG!! Is it that simple?? What was I doing since morning.. I was trying to add parameters to <a> tag and went crazy.. This works like a charm!! Thanks a ton :)